# Qt - change cursor to hourglass and disable cursor

Tags: qt, mouse-cursor

Currently I am working on a Qt program. To prevent the user from interacting with the application when a long task is running, I tried [overriding the cursor](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#setOverrideCursor) by calling

```
QApplication::setOverrideCursor(QCursor(Qt::WaitCursor));
```

However, mouse click events aren't disabled.

Is there any way to disable mouse click events without disabling all widgets of GUI?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I spent a lot of time to find a way to *actually* prevent user interaction in Qt and it occurs that event filtering seems to be an acceptable solution.

Here an example:

```
class AppFilter : public QObject
{
protected:
    bool eventFilter( QObject *obj, QEvent *event );
};

bool AppFilter::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    switch ( event->type())
    {
    //list event you want to prevent here ...
    case QEvent::KeyPress:
    case QEvent::KeyRelease:
    case QEvent::MouseButtonRelease:
    case QEvent::MouseButtonPress:
    case QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick:
    //...
    return true;
    }
    return QObject::eventFilter( obj, event );
}
```

Then when you what to lock:

```
qapp->setOverrideCursor(Qt::WaitCursor);
qapp->installEventFilter(filter);
```

And unlock:

```
while( qapp->overrideCursor()) //be careful application may have been lock several times ...
    qapp->restoreOverrideCursor();
qapp->removeEventFilter(filter);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a different approach that helped for my application: While a user event is being processed, new mouse clicks/button presses are usually only processed when the currently running task calls Q(Core)Application::processEvents(). This is often used in order to force a repaint, e.g. when a progress bar changes. Note that this may be part of any included Qt-based 3rd party libraries, too.

If you change these calls to

```
QApplication::processEvents( QEventLoop::ExcludeUserInputEvents );
```

mouse clicks which happen during your long task will be processed after the task is done. Of course there may be occasions where you don't want to delay your user input events so you have to check that for every single processEvents() call.

If your 3rd party libs have processEvents() calls and you cannot change them, you will be stuck with the same problem I fear.

Comment: processEvents can be tricky, especially if you receive a Quit-Notificaton within processEvents. Beside the mouse events, keyboard events would be filtered, too. Thus closing the application could be disabled, too.

Comment: Interruption of longer tasks is an issue indeed. If you want that, I guess an own event loop will be the only possibility.

Answer (score 0):

setOverrideCursur only changes the cursor appearance.
To disable user input, you could pop up a progress dialog or filter mouse / keyboard events in the event loop.